# "possible nonthreadsafe access to session" error in @PostRemove event listener

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, thread-safety

In my SpringBoot app, I want to set up an event listener that gets triggered upon an entity deletion. Currently, I have this:

```
@EntityListeners(NordigenConnectionListener::class)
@Entity
class NordigenConnection(
...
)

@Component
private class NordigenConnectionListener {

    private val nordigenConnectionService: NordigenConnectionService by autowired()

    @PostRemove
    fun onPostRemove(nordigenConnection: NordigenConnection) {
        nordigenConnectionService.deleteConnectionDataInNordigen(nordigenConnection)
    }
}
```

(Note the custom way how `NordigenConnectionService` is autowired. That's necessary because event listeners are not autowired by Spring in a standard way. I don't think that's causing an issue, though. I can add details if it turns out that it does.)

In my other service I'm deleting all existing NordigenConnections. The PostRemove event listener works fine when there's a single NordigenConnection. Once there are more of them, though, the second event listener invocation fails on this call inside the `deleteConnectionDataInNordigen` method:

```
nordigenTokenRepository.findByClient(nordigenConnection.client)
```

The error is `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible nonthreadsafe access to session`.

Since I'm not managing the session myself and my request is running in a single thread, I would like to understand:

- what's really going on
- how can I prevent this issue

Hibernate version: 5.6.14

Comment: The find triggers a flush, which might be problematic, why not just a `deleteByClient` which wouldn't need that. Also if this is a bi-directional relationship you could specify cascade and that remove orphans.

Comment: deleteConnectionDataInNordigen (where findByClient is called) removes the client from some 3rd party service. So it's really not just deleteByClient.

Comment: could you please provide code of the`deleteConnectionDataInNordigen `

Comment: also did you try to use spring's `TransactionalEventListener ` ?

Comment: @DmitriiBocharov deleteConnectionDataInNordigen is just calling a chain of methods and eventually, there's the `findByClient` which fails on the second invocation of the event listener.

Comment: I did not try to use TransactionalEventListener as this seems to serve a different purpose (reacting on transaction phase transitions instead of the entity lifecycle).